# How to display java map data received from backend at angular /typescript UI?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have multiple rows as such (key1,key2) below coming from backend in a varaible 'detailsMap : any' ,which need to display at UI. Please suggest how can do in Typscript/angular2

> key1 : { Name:'ABC' , address :'JKL street 123', phone:'012345678' }
>
> key2 : { Name:'QER' , address :'STR street 123', phone:'888888888' }

Need to show as something/access like below in a fixed static template. Though below sample is not working. Get error as ***'Test.html:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'key1' of undefined***

```
    <div >
        <div >{{
        detailsMap['key1'].Name}}</div>
        <div >{{
        detailsMap['key1'].address}}</div>
    </div>
    <div >
        <div >{{
        detailsMap['key2'].Name}}</div>
        <div >{{
        detailsMap['key2'].address}}</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to first convert the java map data to array of json object using object Mapper and then send the data to angular. Then you can simply loop over array of json object received from server and display it in UI.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div> item.name </div>
    <div> item.address </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Need to maintain the display order of elements like key1 data first and then key2. Backend can send data in any order.

Comment: You can always sort your data, the Object Mapper will maintain the order of the data..I would suggest you to add a new filed `ID` if you cannot sort data based on your existing data,

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved ,as by the error , the array 'detailsMap' was not visible to template.